# Where to put the witness disk in Windows Failover Cluster?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster, windows-cluster

I have built a Windows Failover Cluster but I am really confused about in which network should the Witness reside? In my current configuration the Witness is in the Heartbeat network.